After upgrading to .NET 9, simple C# statement triggers fatal error in Visual Studio 2022 when Control-C is used to exit
I noticed that .NET 9 is now available as an option in Visual Studio 2022 so I tried upgrading from .NET 8. My applications continue to run as expected, with one problem: I'm getting a fatal error when halting my console applications using Control-C.
Here's the error I'm receiving:

This applies to all of my console applications that make use of the WebBuilder class. The simplest program that will consistently trigger the error is:
internal class Startup
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await WebApplication.CreateBuilder().Build().RunAsync();
    }
}

This code was entered into a new console project, in a new solution, where the top line in the project file has been changed to:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
In addition, launchsettings.json has been deleted to prevent Brave browser from launching when the app is run. The error still occurs even if this file is present; I just deleted it to remove Brave from the equation.
The app itself works fine. It's only the shutdown, when triggered by Control-C or clicking the close button (X) in the console window, that immediately triggers a fatal error with no hints written to the Event Log.
Interestingly, when the app shuts itself down using IHostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication, the shutdown is smooth. There are no errors.
Running the application from the Powershell command line instead of the debugger causes the error to go away. The error only manifests when the debugger is attached.
Reverting the project from .NET 9 back to .NET 8 also causes the error to go away.
Googling this particular error turns up nothing. Any ideas?

Have you Perform a clean rebuild of your project. Delete the bin and obj folders manually and rebuild?

Are you using asp.net core project?

@VikramBose Yes. I deleted the .vs folder too. Recall that this error can be reproduced on a brand new project, so it's not an issue of stale data remaining in the build directories.

@MinxinYu-MSFT Yes. These projects were originally console projects but were upgraded to ASP.NET Core (Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web") because I needed the GRPC support that ASP.NET Core provides.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Could you please help to confirm whether you are testing with the latest version of VS 2022 preview? Based my test, I didn't reproduce your issue.

@TinyWang Yes, I'm using Visual Studio 17.12.0 Preview 1 as of 2024-08-21. Clicking Help > Check for Updates yields, "Visual Studio is up to date."

Thank you for your confirmation, I test with the same version VS and it worked in my side, could you please help share a detailed step for reproducing the issue?

@TinyWang The description in my main post is the simplest way to reproduce. Create a console application. Change project file top line to reference Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web". Make sure framework tag is set to net9.0. Copy paste the code above into a file called Startup.cs. Run the app in the debugger. Hit Control-C. If this doesn't reproduce the error for you, maybe it's something on my side.

I test again in my side which still worked https://i.sstatic.net/4atYooxL.png  I'm afraid it's related to your local environment, maybe you could try to repair your VS?

@TinyWang Understood. Thanks for trying.

@TinyWang Official response from MSFT: "Hi! We are sorry about the issue. It seems this is related to our debugger support for CET that is causing the error. Our team will get back to you if either more information is needed, a workaround is available, or the issue is resolved." Not sure what CET is and Googling it didn't help me understand it any better, and it's definitely not something I intentionally turned on, but apparently that's the source of the issue.

@TinyWang Per MSFT, the fix is to add the following line to the project file: <CetCompat>false</CetCompat>. I can confirm that this causes the error to go away.

Thank you a lot for your  sharing @ChadDecker!

@ChadDecker Thanks for sharing. It seems to be described here. Can you post your solution as answer and mark it as answer?

@Pieterjan Just tried to do so, but it wants me to run through a bunch of CAPTCHA puzzles. I don't do puzzles. Feel free to answer on your own if you'd like.
